# AngularJS appending path after url?

Tags: angularjs

I'm new to AngularJS. So far I have been working with a page in root (/), and I haven't seen any issues with the navigation.

Now I added a path - "entries". I see AngularJS is appending the path again, so

```
http://localhost:9000/entries
```

becomes:

```
http://localhost:9000/entries#/entries
```

And also a request with parameters, like:

```
http://localhost:9000/entries?par1=a&par2=1
```

becomes:

```
http://localhost:9000/entries?par1=a&par2=1#/entries?par1=a&par2=1
```

I read: [$location doc](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services.%24location)

But still I don't quite understand what's going on here. Is this correct behaviour? If not, how do I turn it off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the correct behavior. Changing paths in angular does not actual correspond to a change in the URL itself, just the fragment (what comes after the #). This is how angular (and JS frameworks in general) keep track of your location and changes it without refreshing.